# Will wear / is going to wear / is wearing?

Tags: will-vs-going-to

I got this question on the exam and I don't know what the answer would be?

> A: I don't feel well enough to go to the station to meet him.
>
> B: I (meet) him for you. Tell me how I can recognize him.
>
> A: He (wear) a black and white school cap.

All I know is the answer to B is `I will meet him for you.`
Please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A: I don't feel well enough to go to the station to meet him.
>
> B: I will meet him for you. Tell me how I can recognize him.
>
> A: He **will be wearing** a black and white school cap.

You are correct that 'will meet' should be used for B. 'Will meet' uses the simple future tense, which is the tense used to discuss an activity that begins and ends at a point of time in the future.

'Will be wearing' uses the future continuous tense, which is used when discussing an activity that starts in the future and will continue to occur for a period of time after that.

The last sentence could be replaced with:

> He **is going to be wearing** a black and white school cap.

'Going to be wearing' is more likely to be used if 'he' has deliberately planned in advance to wear a black and white school cap, e.g. just so that he can be spotted in a crowd.

If A is simply predicting what 'he' would wear based on past evidence (e.g. that was what he usually wears), then either 'will be wearing' or 'is going to be wearing' are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir! My teacher said the answer is "He is wearing...". I think your answer is right and you made it very clear to understand but what do you think about my teacher's answer?

Comment: @linkrinne  Your teacher has chosen to use the Present Continuous tense. This is used when describing an activity that is currently occurring and will continue to occur for a period of time into the future. In this case either the Present Continuous or Future Continuous could be used. I personally think that the Future Continuous is a better fit, as A is telling B what they need to look for when B picks 'him' up at some future time. However, if A knows that 'he' will be wearing his cap both now and at the time that 'he' is picked up, then Present Continuous also works.